# Firebase Location to Maps

Tags: swift, firebase, annotations, firebase-realtime-database, maps

I am trying to add my locations values from firebase and turn them into annotation within my app. This is the code I have at the minute which is not working! Looking for a helping hand, feel like I am very close to getting this right but I have hit a mind block!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "locations")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            guard let locationData = item as? FIRDataSnapshot else { continue }
            let locationValue = locationData.value as! [String: Any]

            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationValue["lat"] as! Double, longitude: locationValue["lng"] as! Double)
            let name = locationValue["name"] as! String
            self.addAnnotation(at: location, name: name)


        }
    })
}



func addAnnotation(at location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String) {

    // add that annotation to the map

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.title = location["name"] as? String

        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["lonitude"] as! Double)

        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)



}


}
```

My code is now working but I am getting this issue:

```
Could not cast value of type "NSTaggedPointerString' (0x10a708d10) to 'NSNumber' (0x109d10488).
```

Relating to this line of code:

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationValue["lat"]   as! Double, longitude: locationValue["lng"] as! Double)
```

I have read something about converting a string to double but there is no string in this line? Can anybody help please?

Updated Code Subtitle

[Subtitle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQmep.png)

Update Error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWrru.png)

Comment: Please explain "not working" and include a sample of your JSON data.

Comment: you're working too hard here - in your method `addAnnotation`, you don't have a dictionary any more, you already have a location and a name - just use those variables

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely storing the coordinates as `String` objects in your Firebase database. That's the most common reason that would cause that error. In that case, try the following

```
let lat = Double(locationValue["lat"] as! String)
let lng = Double(locationValue["lng"] as! String)
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
```

**Update**

Some location entries of your database are stored as `String` objects, others as floating point numbers. You should have a consistent structure (i.e all of them be strings or doubles).
Either way, here's a solution for your error:

```
var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

if let lat = locationValue["lat"] as? String {
    // stored as String
    let lng = Double(locationValue["lng"] as! String)!
    location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lat)!, longitude: lng)
}
else {
    // stored as a floating point number
    let lat = locationValue["lat"] as! Double
    let lng = locationValue["lng"] as! Double
    location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Just remove the `let` here

[image: Error line]

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction of how to be able to show and hide annotations dependent on their subtitle. I am thinking I would need to create a table view with three options "all", "skateparks" and "street skating".  When I click on a certain view only those annotations are shown